# Windows 10 system managed virtual memory size is very low. Lower than expected. Can I trust it?

Tags: windows-10, performance, virtual-memory, windows-10-v1607, pagefile

On Windows 10 Home laptop with 8 GB of RAM, the system managed 'Recommended' paging file size is 1905 MB.

Everything I've read says the setting should be from 1.5 to 4 times the size of your RAM. Windows recommended size is about 0.2 time my RAM.

Can this be right?

Should I trust this recommendation, or should I set a custom paging file size?

Comment: Are you running out of virtual memory.  What you should do is allow Windows to increase the page, as it is needed, allowing Windows to determine how much you actually need.

Comment: The recommendation of a pagefile 1.5 x RAM size or higher is quite old, dating to a time when memory sizes were much smaller. From Vista and later the default is usually only 1 x RAM size and that is probably more then you need. With 8 GB RAM a 2 GB pagefile is probably enough. If not you will get out of memory warnings due to approaching the commit limit (roughly RAM size + pagefile size). The warnings have nothing to do with RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you arent exceeding the 2GB it has assigned itself, you are fine.  Everything you read is **wrong**.  You only need a page file as big as you *actually* need.  Anything above that is wasted storage space, and anything below will hinder performance.  What that size is will be determined by how you use your computer. You have 8GB of RAM, which is a fairly decent amount, more than most people use.  If Windows assigned 2GB and you arent paging, then you are perfectly fine.